# Rails: Display meeting if meeting.date > Date.now

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, controller, conditional-statements

I'm new on Ror,
I would like to display on my view all my passed meetings, not my upcoming meeting.
It's not hard but...I don't find how to solve this... :-(
Thk in advance
Here is my code:

schema.rb:

```
  create_table "meetings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "start_time"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.string "details"
    t.string "address"
    t.boolean "highlight"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_meetings_on_user_id"
  end
```

PagesController.rb:

```
def meeting
   @meetings = Meeting.where(meeting.start_time < Date.now)
end
```

Meeting.html.erb:

```
<div class="row">
  <% @meetings.each do |meeting| %>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
    <div class="panel panel-default box-shadow">

      <div class="panel-heading preview">
        <%= image_tag "foiredeparis.jpg", width: 20  %>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
          <strong><%= meeting.name %></strong>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
          <%= image_tag "place.png", heigth:15, width: 30 %><br> <strong><%= meeting.address %></strong><br>
          <%= image_tag "date.png", heigth:20, width: 45 %><br> <%= meeting.start_time %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `meeting` method:

```
def meeting
   @meetings = Meeting.where('start_time < ?', Time.now)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

pages_controller.rb

```
def meeting 
  @meetings = Meeting.where(“start_time < ?”, Time.now)
end
```

Hope it works.